# Expected value and variance of an example problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, variance

I have a probability problem that I don't know if I solved it correctly.
It says:

Two balls are drawn simultaneously from a box with 5 blue and 5 red balls. If they are of the same color you win 1,10 euro. Otherwise you lose 1 euro. Calculate expected value and variance.

I first build the sample space $S=\{(w_{1},w_{2})|\forall w_{1},w_{2}\in(Blue=0,Red=1)\}$

Than we are interested in the two events A={I Win$=(0,0)\cup(1,1)$} and B={I lose$={(w_{1},w_{2})|\forall w_{1},w_{2}\in(0,1)},w_{1}\neq w_{2}$}

The probability $P(A)$ is equal to: $P(A)=\frac{\binom{5}{2}*\binom{5}{0}}{\binom{10}{2}}*2=\frac{4}{9}$ and therefore we have P(B) that is $P(A)=1-P(B)=\frac{5}{9}$

The expected value is $E(X)=1,10*\frac{4}{9}-1*\frac{5}{9}=\frac{-11}{5}$
and the variance is $V(X)=\sum_{1}^{2}(x_{i}-E(x))^2*P(X=x_{i})=(1,10+\frac{11}{5})^2*\frac{4}{9}+(-1+\frac{11}{5})^2*\frac{5}{9}=5,64$
I am right or have I done some mistakes?

Comment: I think your sum for expected value is ok, but the final value is incorrect...please check your arithmetic. This will also change the value of the variance. (Note: It is unreasonable for the expected value to be outside the range of possible values.)

Comment: $\mathsf E(X)=\frac{-1}{15}$  and *not* $\frac{-11}5$

Answer (score 1):

Your arithmetic for the expected value seems incorrect.

$E(x)=(110*4/9)+(-1*5/9) = 145/3$

This will in turn throw off your variance calculation.

Comment: The comma is used as a decimal point in many European countries : So the calculation is:$$\dfrac{1.10\times 4 - 5}{9}=\dfrac{-1}{15}$$